# Airflow on Docker missing Module "Google"

Tags: docker, airflow

I am using the puckel airflow image and upgraded the airflow version by editing the dockerfile which includes google and installed apache-airflow-providers-google 2.2.0 as a python dependency and google or gcs as an airflow dependency when I built the container using

```
`docker build --rm --build-arg AIRFLOW_DEPS="google" --build-arg AIRFLOW_DEPS="google" --build-arg PYTHON_DEPS="httplib2==0.18.1" --build-arg PYTHON_DEPS="apache-airflow-providers-google==2.2.0" -t puckel/docker-airflow .`
```

I also added the python packages to my requirements.txt file which is listed below but when I go to airflow on my localhost it still says "Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/otherfolder/dag.py] No module named 'google'." How can I solve this?

The following is my dockerfile where I changed the version

```
# VERSION 1.10.9
# AUTHOR: Matthieu "Puckel_" Roisil
# DESCRIPTION: Basic Airflow container
# BUILD: docker build --rm -t puckel/docker-airflow .
# SOURCE: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
LABEL maintainer="Puckel_"

# Never prompt the user for choices on installation/configuration of packages
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TERM linux

# Airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.10.14
ARG AIRFLOW_USER_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
ARG AIRFLOW_DEPS=""
ARG PYTHON_DEPS=""
ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

# Define en_US.
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_CTYPE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_MESSAGES en_US.UTF-8

# Disable noisy "Handling signal" log messages:
# ENV GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS --log-level WARNING

RUN set -ex \
    && buildDeps=' \
        freetds-dev \
        libkrb5-dev \
        libsasl2-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        git \
    ' \
    && apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get upgrade -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        $buildDeps \
        freetds-bin \
        build-essential \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        apt-utils \
        curl \
        rsync \
        netcat \
        locales \
    && sed -i 's/^# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8$/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/g' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    && useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME} airflow \
    && pip install -U pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install pytz \
    && pip install pyOpenSSL \
    && pip install ndg-httpsclient \
    && pip install pyasn1 \
    && pip install apache-airflow[crypto,celery,postgres,hive,jdbc,mysql,ssh${AIRFLOW_DEPS:+,}${AIRFLOW_DEPS}]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} \
    && pip install 'redis==3.2' \
    && if [ -n "${PYTHON_DEPS}" ]; then pip install ${PYTHON_DEPS}; fi \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -yqq $buildDeps \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf \
        /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
        /tmp/* \
        /var/tmp/* \
        /usr/share/man \
        /usr/share/doc \
        /usr/share/doc-base

COPY script/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY config/airflow.cfg ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}/airflow.cfg
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN chown -R airflow: ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}

EXPOSE 8080 5555 8793

USER airflow
WORKDIR ${AIRFLOW_USER_HOME}
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["webserver"]
```

The following is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
    python:
      image: python:rc-buster
```

the following is my requirements.txt file

```
httplib2==0.18.1
google==3.0.0
pandas==1.2.4
apache-airflow-providers-google==2.2.0
```

The following is the relevant code from the dag:

```
import datetime
import logging
import dateutil
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from airflow import models, utils
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.bigquery_to_gcs import BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook import BigQueryHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

from airflow.hooks.http_hook import HttpHook
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from pandas.errors import EmptyDataError
from pathlib import Path
from lz_warnings import *
from utils import task_fail_slack_alert
import warnings
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your code and the exact error message. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I updated it thank you! Also, I included the full code because I am not sure where I might be missing something.

Comment: but where is your DAG code? The error is in the DAG.

Comment: Updated again. Airflow documentation shows that this operator is part of the gcs extra package "pip install 'apache-airflow[gcp]" so I've tried adding it as a dependency at build. I've tried pip install but I'm not exactly sure where in the directory to do it - from the airflow bash?

Answer (score 0):

To use GCP related features you have to  install the `google` extras. For this, set in your Dockerfile:

```
ARG AIRFLOW_DEPS="google"
```

Then rebuild the Docker image and restart docker-compose.

Comment: Try editing the Dockerfile as I suggested and removing all --build-arg AIRFLOW_DEPS from the command line.

Comment: I see you said Dockerfile sorry I misread! I tried this and it still didn't work. I also tried moving my httplib2 to just the dockerfile and it didn't work. It seems to only accept httplib2 when it is in my requirements.txt file. Can Airflow DEPS be added to requirements.txt?

Comment: Can you login to the airflow container and run `python path_to_your_dag.py` there and then post the output? To see the full stacktrace may help.